# PHP group mysql result by id

Tags: php, mysql

I have table named "table".

```
id | Name | Game_id
1    John    5
2    Paul    7
3    George  5
4    Ringo   7

SELECT * FROM table
```

for which I am trying to output a new "ul" with data-link "id"for each game_id with the "li" consisting of the respective Name,

i.e. ul 1 data-link=5 with li of John and li of George,

ul2 with data-link=7 and li of Paul and li of Ringo.

Comment: tried a `while` ? Show us code please, rather than, i cant get it.

Comment: That is my code. I've tried all sorts of while and foreach loops and have gotten close on some but no cigar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if this is exactly the question you're looking for, and is probably not the most efficient for a large data set, but one way would be to loop through your results and add to an array, using the data-link as a key.

So if:

```
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($results)
```

(or however you're grabbing results). Something like:

```
$array = array();
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $array[$row["Game_id"]][] = $row["Name"];
}
foreach ($array as $Game_id => $arr) {
    echo '<ul data-link="' . $Game_id . '">';
    foreach ($arr as $name) {
        echo '<li>' . $name . '</li>';
    }
    echo '</ul>';
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, however I am getting an error:  Invalid argument supplied for foreach() on the line : foreach ($arr as $name)

Comment: I edited my reply to turn the array into an actual array - does that work?

Comment: Although just to point out if anyone else uses this code, there is a typo with an extra quotation mark at $row[""name"] on line 3

Comment: Good catch - edited

Comment: Legendary bloke

Answer (score 0):

Crudely...

```
<?php

/*
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS my_table;

CREATE TABLE my_table
(id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY
,name VARCHAR(12) NOT NULL UNIQUE
,game_id INT NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO my_table VALUES
(1,'John',5),
(2,'Paul',7),
(3,'George',5),
(4,'Ringo',7);

*/

require('link/to/connection/stateme.nts');

$query = "SELECT * FROM my_table ORDER BY game_id,id";

$result = mysqli_query($conn,$query);

$array = array();
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
$array[] = $row;
}
print_r($array);

?>
```

Outputs

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [name] => John
            [game_id] => 5
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 3
            [name] => George
            [game_id] => 5
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 2
            [name] => Paul
            [game_id] => 7
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [id] => 4
            [name] => Ringo
            [game_id] => 7
        )

)
```

Actually, I prefer Zeth's idea...

```
<?php

/*
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS my_table;

CREATE TABLE my_table
(id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY
,name VARCHAR(12) NOT NULL UNIQUE
,game_id INT NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO my_table VALUES
(1,'John',5),
(2,'Paul',7),
(3,'George',5),
(4,'Ringo',7);

*/

require('../test_pdo.inc');

$query = "SELECT * FROM my_table";

$result = mysqli_query($conn,$query);

$array = array();
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $array[$row['game_id']][] = $row['name'];
}
foreach ($array as $game_id => $arr) {
    echo '<ul data-link='.$game_id.'>';
    foreach ($arr as $name) {
        echo '<li>'.$name.'</li>';
    }
    echo '</ul>';
}

?>
```

Outputs:

```
    - John
    - George

    - Paul
    - Ringo
```

If you agree, accept their answer, not mine.

Comment: Thanks for the additional info